# Cannot find symbol Error p1.getX()

Tags: java

[image: This is the question being asked attached as a picture]

And the code I typed for it is given below:

```
class MyPoint {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public MyPoint(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    public MyPoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setXY(int newx, int newy) {
        x = newx;
        y = newy;
    }
    public int[] getXY() {
        int [] getXYarray = new int[2];
        getXYarray[0] = x;
        getXYarray[1] = y;
        return getXYarray;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
```

But i cannot see what is actually wrong here.
[image: The java compiler gives me this error]
Please tell me where i am going wrong with this as i am very lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third bullet point from the bottom says you need "Getter and setter for the instance variables x and y". Implement those and I suspect your `Tester` will pass.

```
public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
```

Your instructions *also* call for an overloaded constructor that takes a `MyPoint` (a copy constructor)

```
public MyPoint(MyPoint that) {
    this.x = that.x;
    this.y = that.y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The test code tries to use the methods `getX()` and `getY()`.
You do not define those methods, you only define `getXY()`.

(Please provide textual information as text in the future, it would have made answering this easier for me.)